# How to get character matches in Azure Search index instead of substrings

Tags: azure, lucene, tokenize, azure-cognitive-search

I created an Azure index for my `DocumentDB` collection, and it seems to be working fine. The index has properties for a user account like `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `Username`. The problem is the default tokenizer seems to be tokenizing the `Username` field. While I want token matches for the first two fields, I'd like character matching for the usernames. Is there an easy way to achieve this through the Azure portal? If not, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding another answer based on your above comments.  So basically in the best case, what you want to do is prefix, suffix and wildcard search.  So if the username was user246392, you could find it by typing "use", "392" or even "er246".  The prefix is easy, because you could search use* and it would find it.

Kendra Little did a really nice blog post on how to leverage [RegEx with Azure Search](https://littlekendra.com/2016/10/25/wildcard-vs-regular-expressions-lucene-query-in-azure-search/), which can allow you to do the full wildcard part of your ask (i.e. search for "392").

If you wanted to do the suffix search, you can do a trick that is quite efficient where you create a new field that would be a custom analyzer that would index the words in opposite order.  Here is an example of a index schema that would allow this (over suffixName field)

```
{   
"name":"people",
"fields": [
    { "name":"id", "type":"Edm.String", "key":true, "searchable":false },
    {"name": "suffixName", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable":true, "indexAnalyzer":"suffixIndexingAnalyzer", "searchAnalyzer":"reverseText"}
],
"analyzers": [
    {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
        "name": "suffixIndexingAnalyzer",  
        "tokenizer": "keyword_v2",
        "tokenFilters": [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase",
            "reverse",
            "my_edgeNGramForSuffix"
        ],
        "charFilters": []
    },
    {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
        "name": "reverseText",  
        "tokenizer": "classic",
        "tokenFilters": [
            "lowercase",
            "reverse"
        ],
        "charFilters": []
    }

],
"tokenFilters":[  
    {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2",
        "name": "my_edgeNGramForSuffix",
        "minGram": 2,
        "maxGram": 25,
        "side": "front"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Thank you, Liam. This should be a good starter for me. In the meantime, is there a way to get a random set of results (say, random 10-20 records)? If there are many users with similar usernames, typing the same search text will yield the same results. If I randomize the output, everybody has a chance of being seen. I believe Azure Search should natively support this feature.

Comment: There is not a random function, but there is a technique that Yoad Snapir put together that leverages our geospatial capability which I think was incredibly creative.  You can see this documented here: https://medium.com/@yoad/pseudo-random-sorting-with-azure-search-28966ad851ae

Comment: Thanks. It's an interesting article though I'd expect Azure to support this out of the box in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us an example of what you would want to do over this username field?  I am not sure what you mean by character matching.  Is it a RegEx based character match?  If so, perhaps a [custom analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers) that enabled RegEx searched might help for this field?  Please note, RegEx is not as performant as typical indexing as we would need to scan the entire content as opposed to going to the inverted index to find token matches.

Comment: If the user types "abc", I want to show the top 20 records that contain this string as part of the username. I've noticed the default analyzer seems to be matching meaningful tokens only. If the user adds "d", I want to match any username that contains "abcd". I'm trying to create a search UI similar to Twitter and Instagram when you'd look up people by username.

Comment: Also, I understand they use more complex algos to show targeted search results based on user, but for now I want something basic to look up users by their username.